# Angular2 Nativescript: how to pass ListView item on tap

Tags: listview, angular, nativescript

I have a following code:

```
  <ListView [items]="newsList" (itemTap)="onTap($event)" class="list-group">
    <template let-dataitem="item" let-i="index">
      <GridLayout class="list-group-item">
          <Label [text]="dataitem.title"></Label>
          <Label [text]="dataitem.body"></Label>
       </GridLayout>
    </template>
  </ListView>
```

I want to grub this list item with onTap method. here is my component where onTap method is located:

```
@Component({
   selector: "my-app",
   templateUrl: "app.component.html",
   styleUrls: ["app.component.css"],
   providers:[NewsService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  newsList;
  constructor(private router: Router, news: NewsService) {
     this.isLoading = true;
     news.getNews().subscribe(data => {
        this.newsList = data;
     })
  }

  public onTap(item: any) {
     this.isLoading = true;
     let navExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams:{
            "data" : item
        }
     }
     this.router.navigate(['/details'],navExtras);
  }
}
```

On details component I'm just subscriping to queryParams

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
   this.data = params['data'];
});
```

and displaying data..but is't shows `undefined`. 
What am I doing wrong, and how to get data to pass around.

Comment: Not sure of your data structure or your detail view html, but in my app I  mapped details of the data being passed to detail view, e.g. 
`this.singleImage = this.route.queryParams
            .map( params => params['photo'] || 'None');`
then display as:
`<Image class="wall-cover" [src]="singleImage | async" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>`

Answer (score 0):

You declared `let-dataitem="item"` in you template, so **after** declaration you need to listen on tap event:

```
<ListView [items]="newsList" class="list-group">
    <template let-dataitem="item" let-i="index">
      <GridLayout (tap)="onTap(dataitem)" class="list-group-item">
          <Label [text]="dataitem.title"></Label>
          <Label [text]="dataitem.body"></Label>
      </GridLayout>
   </template>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Ignore - it is dataitem, same as assignment of let-item